# OpenTelemetry-dotnet: StartActiveSpan does not create trace

Tags: .net-core, open-telemetry

I am following `OpenTelemetry-dotnet` tutorial from [this](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/instrumentation/net/shim/), but my code is not working as expected.

My `Program.cs` is:

```
using OpenTelemetry.Resources;
using OpenTelemetry.Trace;

const string serviceName = "WebApplication1";

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddOpenTelemetryTracing(tracerProviderBuilder =>
{
    tracerProviderBuilder
        .AddConsoleExporter()
        .AddSource(serviceName)
        .SetResourceBuilder(
            ResourceBuilder.CreateDefault()
                .AddService(serviceName: serviceName, serviceVersion: "1.0.0"));
}).AddSingleton(TracerProvider.Default.GetTracer(serviceName));

var app = builder.Build();

app.MapGet("/test", (Tracer tracer) =>
{
    using var span = tracer.StartActiveSpan("test-span");
    return "response";
});

app.Run();
```

When I send a request to `/test`, it returns `"response"` well but it does not make any trace.

Answer (score 0):

for ASP.NET core

you have to add nuget reference

```
<PackageReference Include="OpenTelemetry.Instrumentation.AspNetCore" Version="1.0.0-rc9.4" />
```

and change the code to

```
 builder.Services.AddOpenTelemetryTracing(tracerProviderBuilder =>
{
    tracerProviderBuilder
        .AddConsoleExporter()
        .AddSource(serviceName)
        .SetResourceBuilder(
            ResourceBuilder.CreateDefault()
                .AddService(serviceName: serviceName, serviceVersion: "1.0.0"))
        .AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation(); // this is required.
}).AddSingleton(TracerProvider.Default.GetTracer(serviceName));
```

hope it is helpful.

Comment: I also tried it too, but I wanna make a trace manually without auto instrumentation. In this [document](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/instrumentation/net/shim/), there does not include `OpenTelemetry.Instrumentation.AspNetCore` but it seems to make a trace well.

Comment: I had raised this issue on [github](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry.io/issues/1487) to opentelemetry team asking the same thing. they are now correcting the documentation to include `AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation` . so yes current documentation is not correct and that's why it does not work with sample given in document.